# How Spring Data PagingAndSortingRepository works

Tags: java, database, spring, pagination, spring-data

When I call `findAll(Pageable)`, does it select everything from database and does filtering and sorting on application, or create internal queries which will actual fetch just the paged data from database. If former, how could I isolate paging logic to database tier? Where I can find proper documentation for PagingAndSortingRepository? Spring docs doesn't even mention about this vital concern.

Comment: How it works, depends on what you use. For JPA it works different then for Mongo or Redis. To figure out how it works, check the desired repository implementation.